# Entry level doing development at customer site alone - normal?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, work-environment

Is doing developing/programming/bug-testing on site alone at a customer's workplace/environment a normal practice? I am a salaried, entry level developer. With being entry level, the 'this is above my pay grade' cliche comes to mind. Something to note: although entry level, I handle all projects start to finish ( from design, to coding, to customer support, literally everything...)

I ask because I want to use this experience as one of many negotiating tools in the future, whether it be where I am at now... or elsewhere.

Comment: Buddy, you got a great opportunity to learn and grow. Just keep following the best practices and do your job as honestly as you can and you could go places. Btw, this is perfectly normal- perhaps it could just be the customer's requirement.

Comment: When you say you "handle all projects start to finish" - how long have you been doing this?

Comment: Thank you all for the input. I do realize it's been a great opportunity for me to learn and grow, however, I believe I maybe reaching the point where I'm beginning to feel underpaid. Especially, with 3 years of experience now beginning to enter the mid-level range. @HorusKol

Comment: yeah - 3 years is not "entry-level"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its a sign that your company trusts you to not mess up. Thats an awesome opportunity for you to learn, grow, and leverage in future salary negotiations. It may or may not be normal on your company, but in the Industry in general its not, at least not where I live. In any case, it shows huge trust the company already puts forward into you.

As a side node, a job handling full projects and beeing responsible for whole customers looks certainly better in a CV and is certainly worth more then "code snippet a for project b under superivison" in terms of experience.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I guess instead of viewing it as trust, I saw it as potentially being taken advantage of? If that makes sense, but that really is a great, positive way to view it.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal enough in some businesses. It is good experience, but it has a few potential pitfalls as well.

You are fully responsible for any problems, so you need to be very professional how you do things, because you're the number one scapegoat if anything happens. So make sure your instructions are clear and in writing if possible. You need to be careful in all aspects from customers to code.

Apart from that buckle down and do the job, it's experience that you can't buy and the sort of thing that looks great to potential future employers.